# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in Python script when passing files > 1 Kb

Tags: python, permissions, cgi

I am using jquery+ajax to transfer a file  to the server. In the server I have a python script which I copy below which simply gets the file and writes it on disk. The script works perfect for bytes smaller than 1 Kby but for bigger files it throws an exception: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Why does this happen? I do not have access to the server. Should I ask something to the server administrator?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
fileitem = form['photo']

# Test if the file was uploaded
fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)

# strip leading path from file name to avoid directory traversal attacks
if fileitem.filename:  
    fn = fileitem.filename
    open('fotos/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

else:
    message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
""" % (message,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server was not configured to accept files with a size larger than 1 Kby. The solution was asking the server administrator to change this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have permission to open (or write?) whatever file you are trying to work with. Try running the script as super user or change permissions on the directory where you are trying to read/write from

Comment: I do have permissions to write in that path (at least when I upload via FTP and also with other python scripts I saved text files in this path) seems like is only a problem when it tries to save a photo.

Answer (score 0):

From the [getcwd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd):

> **EACCES**
>
> Permission to read or search a component of the filename was denied.

So it sounds like you (or whatever user your server is running as) don't have read permissions for part of your current path.  Are you across a mount point, perhaps?  Or changed the permissions for one of the parent directories?

Comment: What is a mount point? I am working from home and I have client-side script in my PC and I upload the python script in a public server. I have not changed any permissions.